# Is it possible to use the H264 stream from my camera without reencoding to an RTMP endpoint?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

Doing some testing on a Raspberry Pi 4, so I'm trying to use the least amount of resources possible.

I have a webcam connected to the Pi's USB port, and it supports sending the video stream as a compressed H264 stream:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video1

[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x204e1c0] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 640x360 1280x720 1920x1080
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x204e1c0] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 640x360 1280x720 1920x1080
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x204e1c0] Compressed:        h264 :                H.264 : 640x360 1280x720 1920x1080
```

As I'm trying to send the stream to a RTMP endpoint (`nginx-rtmp`), I'm using the following options to send it:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format h264 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -an -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/desk/stream
```

However, I'm not seeing any improvement on the utilization of the CPU in the encoding compared to dropping `-input_format`, leading me to believe that it's still reencoding.

Comment: *"I'm not seeing any improvement ..."* -- Compared to what?

Comment: @sawdust, edited. Essentially I added in the fact that I was comparing using the -input_format flag.

Comment: *"... leading me to believe that it's still reencoding"* -- That's goofy logic.  If ffmpeg chooses the H.264 input anyway even when `-input_format h264` is not specified, then you would also *"not see any improvement on the utilization of the CPU"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a video stream in an output file is encoded or not is solely dependent on the value of the `-codec` option for that stream. Only the value `copy` will skip re-encoding; any other value or lack of the option altogether will force re-encoding irrespective of the source codec.

So change `-c:v libx264` to `-c:v copy`.

(`-c` is a short form for `-codec`)